# Adding "pour" with verbs of motion + infinitive? (eg "J'ai envoyé Paul [pour] faire les courses")

Tags: infinitif

These sentences come from a grammar textbook <sup>1</sup>. *(They are in a section where the textbook discusses situations where an infinitive is used as a direct object of the conjugated verb, and where the logical subject of the infinitive is not the same as the logical subject of the main (ie conjugated) verb.)* :

> Nous avons **emmené** les enfants **faire** un tour sur les manèges.
>
> *We took the children for a ride on the merry-go-rounds.* 
>
> J’ai **envoyé** Paul **faire** les courses. 
> *I sent Paul to do the shopping.*

I'm wondering if these sentences would still be correct (and have the exact same meaning) if I insert the word "pour" just before the infinitive. (This would match more closely the wording used in English) :

> Nous avons emmené les enfants **pour** faire un tour sur les manèges.
>
> J’ai envoyé Paul **pour** faire les courses.

---

<sup>1.</sup> Monique L'Huiller, "Advanced French Grammar", p. 207

Comment: We took the children **to** ride on the merry-go-rounds. Both sentences would have the same to-infinitive structure in English, compared to the French.  I don't see the point of inserting a pour. And anyway, the English does not contain "for".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Nous avons emmené les enfants pour faire un tour sur les manèges.*

   The sentence is not idiomatic and slightly ambiguous as it can be understood that *nous* will made this *tour* with the kids, or even without them. If you want to use *pour*, better to say: *Nous avons emmené les enfants pour qu'ils fassent un tour sur les manèges.* Note also that while *faire un tour sur les manèges* is not impossible, *faire des tours de manège* is much more common.
2. *J'ai envoyé Paul pour faire les courses.*

   Same issues and *pour qu'il fasse les courses* wouldn't really save the sentence.

Comment: 1) With #2, are you saying that #2 is both ambiguous and not idiomatic? Is one of the ambiguous meanings something like maybe I'm the one who is going to *"faire les courses"*? For example, maybe Paul is my teenage son and he is always needing my attention, so I sent him to his friend's house, so that I could finally have enough time to myself to enable to me to do the shopping? 2) In #2, are you able to articulate why "pour qu'il fasse les courses" can't save the sentence?

Comment: 1. Both, although *envoyé Paul* without telling where is unlikely. 2. For the same reason. *J'ai envoyé Paul au supermarché pour qu'il fasse les courses* would work.